# How tf.Session.run work when fetch include both Operation and Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

The value in the red rectangle is confusing:

[image: image1]

The description of `Session.run`:

[image: image2]

Why the value of Variable tmpA is 1.0, it should be 9999.0 since the value of B is 10001.0

Can somebody explain how the function tf.Session.run work?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you check the graph with Tensorboard. The order of calculation cause this result.

When you run line 13 sess.run([A, ops, B]), the program

1. fetch the value of A for tmpA (1.0)
2. assign 9999 to A
3. calculate B

So the value of tmpA is 1.0, and tmpBB is 10001.

Actually the order of evaluation of [A, ops, B] is not deterministic, so there is a possibility that tmpA become 9999 and tmpBB become 3.